# Spark: Sort an RDD by multiple values in a tuple / columns

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

So I have an RDD as follows

```
RDD[(String, Int, String)]
```

And as an example

```
    ('b', 1, 'a')
    ('a', 1, 'b')
    ('a', 0, 'b')
    ('a', 0, 'a')
```

The final result should look something like

```
('a', 0, 'a')
('a', 0, 'b')
('a', 1, 'b')
('b', 1, 'a')
```

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
rdd.sortBy(r => r)
```

If you wanted to switch the sort order around, you could do this:

```
rdd.sortBy(r => (r._3, r._1, r._2))
```

For reverse order:

```
rdd.sortBy(r => r, false)
```

Comment: What about, sort ascending by 1 and descending by 2?