# How to sort the data on multiple columns in apache spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data set like this which I am taking from csv file and converting it into RDD using scala.

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| recent    | Freq      | Monitor  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
|        1  |       1234 |   199090|
|        4  |       2553|    198613|
|        6  |       3232 |   199090|
|        1  |       8823 |   498831|
|        7  |       2902 |   890000|
|        8  |       7991 |   081097|
|        9  |       7391 |   432370|
|        12 |       6138 |   864981|
|        7  |       6812 |   749821|
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

How to sort the data on all columns ?

Thanks

Comment: Which columns do you want to sort on first? You can't sort on all the columns at once, you have to sort on one column first, THEN sort by the next column, etc. We need more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting by multiple fields in Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379516/sorting-by-multiple-fields-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Sorry i am new to spark and scala. Actually i want first column should be sorted in descending order and then i need to sort next two columns in ascending order. I need to give the rank as well.

Comment: Did you already tried something? could you post some code you wrote and the result you achieved?

Comment: I tried to convert into key value pair and then used sortBykey() method but i couldn't get the output.

Comment: val csv = sc.textFile("ranked_data.csv")

// create key-value pair
val pairs = csv.map(x => (x.split(",")(0),x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2)))

val res = pairs.sortBykey()

Comment: It would be helpful for me if you give me some spark scala example similar to my problem.

Comment: Also a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393224/spark-sort-an-rdd-by-multiple-values-in-a-tuple-columns

Answer (score 8):

Suppose your input RDD/DataFrame is called df.

To sort `recent` in descending order, `Freq` and `Monitor` both in ascending you can do:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sorted = df.sort(desc("recent"), asc("Freq"), asc("Monitor"))
```

You can use `df.orderBy(...)` as well, it's an alias of `sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.sortBy(r => (r.recent, r.freq))` or equivalent should do it